# How to remove lines from file with specific string in fixed position in Unix

Tags: unix

I'm a newbie in scripting and I have this problem:
 I have one file that has more than 100k+ records.
I need to remove some records from my file based on some specific position
Like If 'AB123   ' is present in position 38 to 45 than that line should be removed from file before starting the sql loader.

Could any one please help me .

Comment: There are so many different ways you could approach this. You could use `awk`, `sed`, `perl` and many others. You could even use a combination of `cat`, `grep` and `cut`. Your learning curve may not be as bad as you think. Learning any of these tools would be useful long term.

Comment: Do you have fixed positions or can the 6 char long `AB123 ` start on both position 38 or 39?

Comment: When you have a lot different combinations to exclude, you should look for some kinf of config file, like `sed -f exclude_these.sed inputfile`. Awk is also easy when you write each rule on one line `condition {next}`.

Comment: @walter Its fixed position and will start from 38 and end at 45. It can be 'ABC12345' or 'ABC123  '. And the same string can also be present in some other position as well. But i just want to delete the lines if it is present in specific position. If i will delete without checking the position then it will delete other lines as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should test a solution with a smaller file.
I made a testfile with

```
for ((i=0;i<50;i++)); do echo "$((i%11))exampleABC123..$i" ; done > inputfile
```

Every 11th line is one position longer, and ABC starts at position 10 on these lines. How to delete only these lines?
You start counting from the beginning (`^`), accept 9 random chars (`.{9}`) followed by the string that should match, and delete these (`/d`)

```
sed -r '/^.{9}ABC123/d' inputfile
```

When you have more rules the search expression becomes more difficult.
Suppose you also want to delete lines starting with a 5 or ending with a 9.

```
sed -r '/^.{9}ABC123|^5|9$/d' inputfile
```

When you have more rules, make a config file (and be nice by adding comment), like this file `exclude.sed`

```
/^.{9}ABC123/d # Search for ABC123 on position 10
/^5/d # Lines starting with a 5
/9$/d # Lines finishing with a 9
```

Now parse your input with the rules given in your config

```
sed -rf exclude.sed inputfile
```

Comment: walter i tried `sed '/^.{37}ABC123/p' inputfile` but it is displaying all the records

Comment: The answer is about removing the lines. When you want to print only the lines matching the condition, you can use `sed -n '.../p'. The option `-n` suppresses printing lines, and the /p will print the selected lines. When you want to combine removing some lines and selecting others, the easiest method is piping 2 commands: `sed -rf exclude.sed inputfile | sed -nrf printthese.sed`

Comment: Normally you might need a lot ackslashes in `sed`. With `-r` (an option in some sed's) you can do without. When you don't can or want to use the option, commands look like `sed '/^.\{9\}ABC123\|^5\|9$/d' inputfile`. Try that.

Comment: i tried `sed -n '/^.{37\}ABC123*/p' inputfile` but nothing is getting displayed. I checked the count of records using `grep -c ABC123 inputfile' and it gave more than 100K record .

Comment: When you start testing with small files you might have noticed that you are missing a backslash before `}` (and the incorrect `*`), so try `sed -n '/^.\{37\}ABC123/p' `. When that doesn't work, start with simplier commands like `sed -n '/ABC123/p' `

Comment: Thanks Walter, my work is done.Thanks a lot for your response and time